# Showing nearest multiple markers on Google Map API JS V3 from current position of users at range of 30kms

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am creating an Mobile App where user(customer) will see multiple markers of drivers who is on the 30kms of range from the users current position.

I am able to display multi markers, which are stored in the database by using JSON and JQuery.

```
function multimarker(map)
{
        jQuery.ajax({                              
    url: baseurl +  "getdriverlocation.php",
    type: "JSON",
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
       var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);// instead of JSON.parse(data)

        jQuery(myArray).each(function( index, element ) {     
        driverlat = element.driver_lat;
        driverlng = element.driver_lng;
        locations.push([driverlat , driverlng])
});
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 for (i  = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
                 { 

                var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
            drivermarker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng1});
            drivermarker.setMap(map);
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           google.maps.event.addListener(drivermarker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, drivermarker);

        }
      })(drivermarker, i));
                         bounds.extend(latlng1);
                 }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
} 
});

}
```

also able to plot current position on the same map

```
function currentpostionmap()
{
     if ( navigator.geolocation ) {


        function success(pos) 
         {
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
             var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
          var image123 = 'https:///developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image123
        
        });
             multimarker(map);

        }
        function fail(error) {
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5204, 73.8567);
             var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
      
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
           
            });


        }
        // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
    } 
}
```

Now I just want to display only those marker which are at the distance of 30km from the current position.

Else will not be displayed.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add the markers to the map if they meet your criteria. Be sure to include the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry).

```
for (i  = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
  if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1,map.getCenter()) < 30000) {
    drivermarker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng1});
    drivermarker.setMap(map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(drivermarker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, drivermarker);
      }
    })(drivermarker, i));
    bounds.extend(latlng1);
  }
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```